# How can I get the CPU time for a perl system call?

Tags: linux, perl, time, system-calls

I have a perl script that calls external executables using `system()`. I would like to measure the CPU seconds taken by these external programs. Ideally, I would like to run them using the shell builtin `time` command (this is on a Linux system). Something like this:

```
system("time /path/to/command")
```

Now, `time` prints its output to stderr, but in order to do so, launches the command it is given in a separate subshell. This means that in order to capture time's output when running manually in the shell, you need to explicitly use a subshell and redirect the subshell's stderr:

```
$ time ( command > command.log 2> command.er) 2> time.out
```

The file `time.out` will have the output of the `time` command while `command.er` has the stderr of `command`. Unfortunately, the parentheses break perl's system call:

```
$ time ( ls ) 2> er ## works
$ perl -e 'system("time (ls)")'
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

And this means I can't capture the output of `time`. To make matters wors, this seems to be version dependent:

```
$ perl --version | head -n2
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

But if I try the same thing with a newer version:

```
$ perl --version | head -n2
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
$ perl -e 'system("time (ls)")'
file1

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Unfortunately, I need this to run on a production machine so upgrading Perl is not an option. So, how can I time a system call in Perl 5.18? I need the `user` and `sys` values, so simply recording the start and end times won't help. I am willing to use a dedicated module if that's necessary although I would prefer a trick that lets me use the shell's `time`.

---

UPDATE: it turns out the difference in behavior is not because of the newer perl version but, instead, it is because I tested it on an Arch system whose `/bin/sh` is `bash` while the other commands were being run on Ubuntu systems whose `/bin/sh` is `dash`, a minimal shell that doesn't support parentheses for subshells.

Comment: You could use https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny to capture the STDERR directly.

Comment: `sh: 1: Syntax error` indicates that error originates from `/bin/sh`, not from `perl`.

Comment: @el.pescado yes, I know, but it is because of how perl is calling the command. Note that the same thing works fine when run directly in the shell and, more importantly, it works fine when run with a newer version of Perl.

Comment: @simbabque thanks, I'll try that. However, I fear it will only capture the stderr of the command run and not of `time`. The two are separate.

Comment: It's worth remembering that your interactive shell may be different from the shell used by `system` call. Usually `bin/sh` is symlink to `/bin/bash` but AFAIR Ubuntu used `/bin/bash` as interactive shell and `/bin/dash` for executing scripts (which includes `system`).

Comment: Capture::Tiny captures the output of everything that's in the block. That _should_ work.

Comment: @el.pescado yes, I know it can be different, but that's not relevant, the parentheses for the subshell are POSIX. And Ubuntu (well, Debian and by extension Ubuntu) use `dash` as the login shell (which is set to `/bin/sh`), not as the default interactive shell (set to `/bin/bash`). None of this is really relevant here though.

Comment: Try `/bin/sh -c 'time (ls)'` vs `/bin/bash -c 'time (ls)'`. On my system, the latter works whereas the former does not.

Comment: `$ perl -MCapture::Tiny=capture -E 'my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture { system "time ls" }; say $stderr;'` outputs `0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2388maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+114minor)pagefaults 0swaps`, although I don't get why the whitespace is mixed up. On my Perl 5.20.1 with C::T 0.44 I have to explicitly import `capture`, or it will output everything though.

Comment: @simbabque yes! I just tried it and it does indeed work. Please post an answer and I'll accept. Oh, and I used `use Capture::Tiny ':all';` as suggested in the docs and that correctly imported `capture`.

Comment: @el.pescado dammit! Yes, you're also right. Subshells [*are* POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_9_4) but the stupid `dash` seems to not implement them. That's also probably worth an answer. And I also owe you an apology. I had mistakenly assumed the difference was the Perl version. In fact, it was the different shell since I tested the newer perl version on an Arch system whose `/bin/sh` is actually `bash` in POSIX mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny#capture) to capture the STDOUT and STDERR of pretty much anything in Perl.

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture { system "time ls" };

print $stderr;
```

For some reason the output is missing some whitespace on my system, but is  clear enough to parse out what you need.

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2272maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+111minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: Previously I tried this using `qx` and I easily captured the whitespace as well. But now I am also getting the same output!

Comment: Well `qx` is like the backticks. It returns all output, which is the point. But the OP wants `system` specifically, which returns the return code, and not the output.

Comment: @AbhiNickz I realize that. And I don't understand why it's happening. :-/

Comment: Not required to use any such modules, just use backticks, details available in  Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486568/1760065

Comment: @Jerry please reread the question. There is a subshell involved here, and the output redirection you suggest does not work. The OP in this question had already ruled that out before asking.

Answer (score 3):

You've tested the command with `bash`, but you passed it to `sh`.

```
system("time (ls)")
```

is short for

```
system("/bin/sh", "-c", "time (ls)")
```

but you want

```
system("/bin/bash", "-c", "time (ls)")
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I thought it wasn't a shell issue because i) parenthesized subshells are POSIX, so I assumed even `dash` (which is the default `/bin/sh` on Debian-based systems) would support them and ii) it worked on my Arch which has a newer perl version so I had concluded it was a Perl issue, forgetting that Arch uses `bash` as `/bin/sh`. *Sigh*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ time ( ls ) 2> er ## works
$ perl -e 'system("time (ls)")'
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

The problem is that in first case, your shell is probably `/bin/bash` whereas in second case it is `/bin/sh`. If you want to run your command with another shell, you could use [`system LIST`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) form:

```
system("/bin/bash", "-c", "time(ls)")
```

---

Note 1: There's `PERL5SHELL` environmnet value, but that seems to take effect *only* on Win32.

Note 2: If you want to measure CPU time of child process, you could use [Unix::Getrusage](http://search.cpan.org/~taffy/Unix-Getrusage-0.03/lib/Unix/Getrusage.pm) or [BSD::Resource](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/BSD-Resource-1.2911/Resource.pm) modules.