# Get both STDOUT and STDERR of a program or script to a variable in perl

Tags: perl, system, stdout, stderr, backticks

I did lot of google to redirect the both STDOUT and STDERR of a program to a variable in perl, Initially i tried using both **open** and **backticks**, but failed to capture Error signal to the variable.

I am posting this question because Now I got the solution and hope it may helps others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get both STDOUT and STDERR into a variable use following code snippet using backticks (``).

Make sure **2>&1** is places at the end of your command, to redirect STDERR in to STDOUT.

**When wrong command provided,**

```
my $Temp_return;
$Temp_return = `lse 2>&1`;
print "return = " . $Temp_return . "\n";
```

**Error OutPut is,**

```
return = 'lse' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

For  correct command you will get the result accordingly.

As an additional information different methods for executing the command in Perl are.

**system()  :** If you want to execute a command and not interested in reading console output of the executed command.

**exec      :** When you don't want to return to the calling Perl script. use same.

**backticks :** When you want to store /read the console output of the command into a Perl variable. Initial I mistakenly thought, required to use Single cores('') instead, for backticks (``) and get confused, because its almost similar to Single cores(''), please give attention.

**open()    :** When you want to pipe the command (as input or output) to your script.

Hope  it could be helpful for you..... :)

BR,
Jerry James